# How to Properly Use NuGet with Team Development?

Tags: version-control, nuget

So I would like to use NuGet to manage the various projects I use for a specific project my team and I are working on. Up to this point, I have placed my .js library files in the /Scripts directory of my web solution (ASP.NET MVC 2) and referenced those. Of course, this was manual and was annoying to manage during upgrades, etc.

Now that I am using NuGet, I realize that the entire goal of NuGet is to make this fairly painless. In addition, it appears that I shouldn't have to check my packages into my repository (AKA I don't need to manage my external libraries anymore). However, when I grab jQuery (for example) from NuGet, it places its specific files in the /Scripts directory of my project.

Where I get confused - what, if anything, should I check into source control at this point? Do I still check in the /Scripts directory?

In addition, if someone else is working on this project and checks out the solution from source control, are the packages automatically downloaded (assuming the solution comes with a valid packages.config)?

I'm just trying to clarify a couple points before we start using NuGet full-time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two scenarios for NuGet vs VCS: to check-in or not to check-in, that's the question.
Both are valid in my opinion, but when using TFS as VCS, I'd definitely go for a [no-checkin policy for NuGet packages](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/07/18/Continuous-Package-Integration-NuGet-vs-Source-Control.aspx).

That being said, even when using a no-checkin policy for NuGet packages, I'd still checkin the content changes that those NuGet packages have done to my projects. The `\Scripts` folder would be checked-in in its entirety (not selective, not ignored).

The no-checkin policy for packages to me means: not checking in the \Packages folder ([cloak it](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/10/17/Tell-TFS-not-to-add-NuGet-packages-to-source-control.aspx), ignore it), except for the `\Packages\repositories.config` file.

As such, you are effectively not committing any NuGet packages, and when using `Enable-PackageRestore` from the NuGetPowerTools (this will be built-in in NuGet v1.6 just around the corner), any machine that checks out the code and builds, will fetch all required NuGet dependencies in a pre-build step.
This is true for both local development machines as for build servers, as long as `Enable-PackageRestore` is enabled in your solution and points to the correct NuGet repositories (local, internal, external).

If you think about it, when installing a NuGet package that only adds references to some binaries, you'd already be doing the samething in a no-checkin scenario: you would not commit the `\Packages` folder's subfolders, but still, you'd commit the project changes (the added reference).

I'd say, **be consistent** (for any type of package), whether it contains binaries only, content only, or a mix. [Do not commit the packages themselves](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/07/18/Continuous-Package-Integration-NuGet-vs-Source-Control.aspx), do commit the changes to your sources. (if only to avoid the hassle of looking up what changed content-wise)

Comment: Thanks, the "check in project changes" thing is the important piece that was missing!

Answer (score 1):

[NuGet](http://nuget.org/), like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), are artifact repository (artifact being any type of deliverable, including potentially large binary).

The side-effect is for you to not store in an VCS (Version Control System) elements that:

- wouldn't benefit from VCS features (branching, merging)
- would increase significantly the size of the VCS repository (no delta or weak delta storage)
- would be quite hard to remove from a VCS repository (designed primarily to *keep* the history)

But the *goal* is for you to *declare* what you need (and let NuGet fetch it for you) instead of *storing* it yourself.
So you can version `/Scripts` as a placeholder, but you don't need anymore to versioned any of its content now fetched automatically.

Comment: What about automated builds? If the scripts aren't in source control, then how do they get packaged into the build outputs to enable deployment?

Comment: I just used NuGet for the first time in a particular solution. I got jQuery, then edited the .csproj file to see what changes were made. The scripts were just included as content files. I saw nothing that would cause those files to magically appear during an automated build if they were not stored in source control.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: they should appear automagically as part of a build command, which would read a configuration file, call Nuget to get the right artifact versions and download them if they aren't already locally there: that means, no need to include those (libraries, exe, dll, ...) in a VCS anymore. See http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html

Comment: What would cause that to happen in a Team Build. I don't see where the magic comes in. There were no new targets or anything. Also, I hope you're not saying that the version of a package might change from one build to the next. Our QA staff like to know about things like that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: any change to the config file (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) should trigger, at the next build, the necessary artifact update.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the project file that would cause such an update. Did I overlook a new ItemGroup or target?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it depends what project file you are looking at: as mentioned in http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/Managing-NuGet-Packages-Using-The-Dialog, "Files are copied to the solution, references might be added to the project, the project app.config or web.config file might be updated, etc."