# Do Nuget packages need to be added by every developer who works on same VS project?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've added some libraries to a VS 2010 solution using Nuget (RestSharp, Twilio, etc.).  When I pull the same solution down to a new PC from TFS and try to build it, all the references to those assemblies are broken (error "namespace cannot be found...").  Is it necessary for each developer who works on this VS solution for the first time to independently install the same Nuget packages on their PCs?
Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you need to be sure the assemblies are all included in the same relative path so Visual Studio can find them. You can include the solution's nuget packages directories, which is where I think it stores a copy of the libraries to be referenced by the project(s).

Incidentally, including said diretories may be effectively the same as "installing the packages". If you include all the files that NuGet uses in its management of packages, NuGet will behave the same as if you had installed them. But you don't need to do the actual package install via NuGet for it to work... or even have NuGet installed in Visual Studio in the first place. It's just a matter of the proper files being where the Visual Studio project files expect them to be.

Answer (score 5):

As Andrew already have said it's all about the packages' location.

Either you have to check in the entire packages folder with all the packages, or each developer have to install the packages after first checking out. But there is a better way to do this, namely to [use NuGet Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) - which will automatically install all missing  packages when the project is built.

If you use package restore, you only need to check in the repositories.config into your VCS. With TFS you can [cloak the entire packages folder](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/10/17/Tell-TFS-not-to-add-NuGet-packages-to-source-control.aspx) except for the repositories.config, so that TFS doesn't annoy with pending checkins for new packages.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8442160/66849) for guidance on how to use TFS + NuGet.

Comment: This is a good answer, especially considering the additional info related to TFS, which iI've never used.