# What is the use of the Nuget .package directory in my solution root

Tags: nuget

My solution's `.package` folder increases the size of the solution by several orders of magnitude - not including my Mvc app's build folders, of course. The bin folder isn't getting commited to source control and I'm wondering if I can skip out on the nuget folder too without having negative side effects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300459/do-nuget-packages-need-to-be-added-by-every-developer-who-works-on-same-vs-proje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages folder holds the nuget packages' content. In order to be able to use and distribute the solution without it you can enable the [nuget package restore feature](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).